# How can I add "rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1" to my .rpm package?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

Building `.rpm` package from the sources (`.src.rpm`) with rpmbuild. How can I add dependency of `rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1`.
Can not change my `.spec` file.
Tried to add macros `%__lzma /usr/bin/xz`, but it didn't take my any effect.

```
# rpm --showrc | grep xz
-14: __lzma     /usr/bin/xz
-14: __xz       /usr/bin/xz
```

Comment: Don't know why, but its work: add macro %_binary_payload w?.xzdio, where ? - amount of compression power

Comment: This question over at ServerFault may answer your question:
http://serverfault.com/questions/280099/how-do-i-install-an-rpm-that-complains-about-rpmlibfiledigests-4-6-0-1